# CSS Анимация rotate изменяет положение элемента

Tags: css, css-animation

Всем добрый день, пытаюсь уже 2-рой день сделать анимацию для ветряков:
http://vp.kl.com.ua/kraina-maray/

Проблема состоит вот в чем:
Когда крутиться элемент (они же лопасти от ветряка) он меняет понемногу свою позицию, как зафиксировать эти элементы так что-бы он крутились не меняя свои позиции? Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Второй день? :D

Comment: Раньше анимацией не занимался и по этому так влип)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно переопределить центр вращения с помощью `transform-origin`:

```
.blade{
    ...
    transform-origin: 50% 46%;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, помогло!

Comment: @Puvvl в таком случае отметьте этот ответ как правильный, нажав на галочку слева.